# Combine Multiple Excel Ranges Across Worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create a consolidate range consisting of ranges spread across multiple worksheets in Excel 2007. What I wish I could do is to use the VBA UNION function in a cell formula, but that doesn't seem to be an option.

I can handle VBA if necessary, but there's no telling if someone who would have to maintain this in the future would be able to.

My ultimate goal is to run functions such as MAX, MIN, AVERAGE, etc across the consolidated range.

Any help out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comma seperated list of ranges as a parameter to functions, eg

```
=MIN(Sheet1!A1:C10,Sheet2!B7:D11)
```

of using named ranges

```
=MIN(NameOnSheet1,NameOnSheet2)
```

or a 3D reference to refer to the same cells on a contiguous range of sheets, eg

```
=MIN(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1:C10)
```

Comment: That load scream you just heard was me being hit by the clue-by-four. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a named range.

If you highlight area 1 then while holding Ctrl highlight area 2.... both should appear to be selected.

now go to forumlas -> define name and give your new range a name (ie SuperRange)

Now to get the max you could enter

```
=max(SuperRange)
```

to get the result

Comment: -1 `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVERAGE` do not work with this type of range

Comment: Yes they do, why do you think they don't

Comment: It would work if SuperRange was defined as a contigious range `(Sheet1:Sheet4!A1:C10)`. It would fail if it was defined as `Sheet1!B1:D10,Sheet2!C7:E11`

Comment: @brettdj The named range is defined as you decribed.... but I didn't get any error messages, and the calculations returned the correct answer. I tested this before posting my answer. For the sake of my sanity could you elaborate what and how this solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Pynner, I tried both examples in xl03 and xl10, the contiguous range worked, the later didn't. Which didn't surprise me, xl is often flakey in 3D. Is the later approach working for you? The later example does of course work if MIN is in the range name itself, ie SuperUser is defined as `=MIN(Sheet1!G9:I18,Sheet2!H15:J19)`

Comment: @brentdj Thanks for discussing with me.... I was testing a distributed range on a single sheet. I missed the multiple sheets portion.

Comment: @Pynner No probs.I upvoted your answer given your efforts to close this out. I suggest you edit your post to note that you answer works accross multiple sheets if the range is contiguous, but not if it varies.